# How to change the structure of an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array but the structure isnt good so I wanted it to change.

The array is an array with arrays in it, but 1 is always empty so I dont need this one, and therefor there's no need for a multilevel array.

Current array

```
array(

    [0] => array( 
        [0] => some value
        [1] => some value
    ),
    [1] => array( empty so this one must be removed )

)
```

The way that I want it to be

```
array( 
        [0] => some value
        [1] => some value
    )
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like below.

```
array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array());
```

**For Example:**

```
$a = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));
$result = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());
```

**Result:**

```
array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) inside a loop. Something like -

```
$array = [
[1, 2],
[],
[4]
];
$temp = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
  $temp = array_merge($temp, $a);
}
print_r($temp);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array and add the non empty arrays elments, as explained below, (without using inbuilt function)

```
<?php
$array = [[1, 2], [], [4]];
$temp = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
   if(!empty($a)) {
      foreach($a as $b)
      $temp[] = $b;
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp);
/* result
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
)
*/
?>
```

Comment: You can dump the empty check: `$in  = [[1, 2], [], [4]];
foreach($in as $a)
    foreach($a as $b)
        $out[] = $b;`

Comment: @Progrock yes you are right, but in case if the array contains null or blank string it will append the element in the output e.g. `[""]` or `[null]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly cheap code wise way of flattening

```
$array = [[1, 2], []];
$flat = array_merge(...$array);
```

The problem is if the first level of the array isn't all arrays, it falls over

Comment: If worried about an element not being an array, you could adapt Sougata's answer and cast array_merge's second argument to an array.